# Git: Copy Repo To New Directory To Continue Working

Tags: git

I've been working in directory v3 (i.e. master).

I am now in a new directory, v4.

While in v3, I created the branch v4.

How do I bring in the `.git` file from directory v3 into directory v4 and continue posting to the new branch?

I initially thought of cloning v3 into v4 but that clones all the source files as well. I don't need all that, just the `.git` file if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make a new repo in v4 using git init. It's possible to merge these repos later..

Or  if your v4 folder is already a git repo, do this from v3 folder:

```
git checkout v4
git pull ../v4 master # pulling branch master from repo in v4 directory
```

(or please refer to the docs of git pull if I'm wrong)